# Play! Framework 2.X WebJar with *.html files: access from Controller

Tags: playframework-2.0, webjars

We are trying to create a plugin model for our Play! project. The plugin should include Java/Scala code and html template file (with css, js).

Examples for WebJars describe how to reference static assets, like css and js, but we can't find how to include and utilize (from Controller) html template files.

```
public static Result index(Http.Context ctx) {
    ...
    return ok(views.html.ourHtmlTemplate.render();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the WebJar in the controller?

Comment: I need to put jar file with (java, css, js and html) in Play! folder and be able to render html (from that jar) using Play! template engine (template is rendered from the Controller). Jar file is added to the Play! as a dependency.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what you are trying to do.  Which Jar and which Play folder?

Comment: The idea is create web management console application with extension of functionality using plugins, plugins should be able to render complete web page and contain some Controller side logic. Plugins will be distributed as jar files and will include all required components. I looked at WebJar as one possible solution to the problem. Plugin jar will be placed in Play! classpath folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can package any Play app (views, controllers, etc) up as a reusable library.  That Play app's dependencies can be transitive using the Maven / POM support in sbt.  So if the project depends on WebJars, those dependencies can transitively be pulled into another project.

Since Play projects are really just sbt projects just look into how to create reusable libraries with sbt: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html